# GoCov Getting Test Coverage

Tags: go, testing, makefile, gnu-make, test-coverage

I have a test in my application but my test coverage is saying that I have 0% coverage.

Below is the make command that I am using:

```
# TODO: FIX this it works if I go into the src directory and manually run this command but not from makefile
coverage:
    cd src/test && \
    echo $(pwd) && \
    go test -mod=mod -coverprofile=coverage.out -coverpkg=./... ./... && go tool cover -func=coverage.out
```

If I run my test using IntelliJ IDE like this (see picture below), I get a coverage of  2.2%.
[image]

**What should I do to my makefile command for my gocov to recognize my test case?**

Comment: What command is IntelliJ running?

Answer (score 0):

The fix was pretty simple, all I had to do was add another `.` in front of the slash so instead of `-coverpkg=./... ./...` I had to use `-coverpkg=./... ./...`. Below is my make command, I also added gocov reporting.

```
coverage: coverage-tools
    cd src/test && \
    go test -mod=mod -coverprofile=coverage.out -coverpkg=../... ../... && \
    mkdir -p $(REPORT_DIR) && \
    cp coverage.out $(REPORT_DIR)/ && \
    $(GOPATH)/bin/gocov convert $(REPORT_DIR)/coverage.out | \
    $(GOPATH)/bin/gocov-html > $(REPORT_DIR)/coverage.html
    rm ./src/test/coverage.out
```